Receiving bad request error 400 from GET with urlencoced character
I'm sending a GET request via Insomnia to my server and the URL contains an encoded pipe character:
https://myhost/publication/info/11%20%7C%20Friends
All I get in return is a bad request error 400.
I tried to send the pipe character without encoding, but it makes no difference.
What am I missing here? Is there a setting on the server side that needs to be edited?
Update:
The same error occurs with other encoded characters like ">" or "<".

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Hi @JosefZ, what do you mean by "reproducible example"? It's a simple GET Request without parameters (strictly spoken, the parameter is contained in the path). When I send it via Insomnia, I receive an error 400 claiming "bad request". I dont know how to make this behaviour reproducible to anyone without access to my server.
